# Providing menu route parameter values from url

Tags: 8, routes, navigation

Suppose I have the following route in my ej.routing.yml file:

```
ej.form.user.profile:
 path: '/user/{user}/ej_profile'
 defaults:
   _title: 'EJ Profile'
   _form: '\Drupal\ej\Form\User\ProfileForm'
 requirements:
   _role: 'authenticated'
   user: \d+
```

Now I want to add a menu based on the above route to Tools menu. So I use the following in ej.links.menu.yml file:

```
ej.user.profile:
  title: 'EJ Profile'
  description: 'EJ Profile'
  route_name: ej.form.user.profile
  menu_name: tools
  weight: 100
```

However this gives me an exception saying: Symfony\Component\Routing\Exception\MissingMandatoryParametersException: Some mandatory parameters are missing ("user") to generate a URL for route "ej.form.user.profile".

The same works as a task entry. Basically I have a custom form that extends user profile to integrate with a third-party system and I need the user id from the url to fetch appropriate user's information.

How can I have the menu to pick route parameter from the url?

Comment: I think that (out of the box) only local tasks and actions pick up route parameters from the current route.

Comment: You can try using a custom class for the menu item. And then add your route parameter as you like.

Comment: Do you want to add multiple menu items (one for each user in the DB)? Or do you want to add a single menu item (just for the current user)?

Answer (score 0):

As @Eyal mentioned, "You can try using a custom class for the menu item. And then add your route parameter as you like."

I've done this by extending the [MenuLinkDefault](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Menu%21MenuLinkDefault.php/class/MenuLinkDefault/8.2.x) class and then assigning my menu link to use the class in my MY_MODULE.links.menu.yml.

For example my ExampleMenuLink class:

```
namespace Drupal\my_module\Plugin\Menu;

use Drupal\Core\Menu\MenuLinkDefault;

class ExampleMenuLink extends MenuLinkDefault {

  /**
   * Determine my dynamic parameter and add it to the route's parameters.
   */
  public function getRouteParameters() {
    $original_params = $this->pluginDefinition['route_parameters'] ?: [];

    $my_dynamic_params = [
      'example_param' => $this->getMyDynamicRouteParameter(),
    ];

    return $my_dynamic_params + $original_params;
  }

  /**
   * Disable my menu link if a real dynamic parameter can't be determined.
   */
  public function isEnabled() {
    // If we can't determine our route parameter, disable the link.
    if ($this->canDetermineMyRouteParameter() !== TRUE) {
      return FALSE;
    }

    return parent::isEnabled();
  }

}
```

Then, my MY_MODULE.links.menu.yml file:

```
my_module.my_custom_route_link:
  title: 'My Custom Link'
  route_name: my_module.my_custom_route
  route_parameters:
    example_param: 0 # Dynamically set in ExampleMenuLink.
  class: Drupal\my_module\Plugin\Menu\ExampleMenuLink
```

Since the route parameter is required, I could only get this to work by passing a dummy parameter in my link definition, e.g. `example_param: 0`. In my case, I was passing an entity id so 0 would never be valid. This parameter will never be used anyway because in the ExampleMenuLink::isEnabled() method, I disable the link if I can't get an appropriate value for my dynamic parameter. Additionally, I implement ExampleMenuLink::getRouteParameters() to add my dynamic parameter and pass it to the route.